# How do I get Heroku to find and load my main java file

Tags: java, heroku, discord, discord-jda

When I try to deploy my discord bot program nothing happens and the logs say this:
`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

`Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.Main.java`

My Procfile is in the root of the repository and it has this line of code:
`Worker: java src/main/java/Main.java`

I was following a youtube guide on how to get my own discord bot running on Heroku and I copied everything perfectly. The exact same project runs with no errors in IntelliJ.
How do I get Heroku to find and load my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run a Java source file (`.java` extension), not a compiled class file. You're also not specifying a classpath where Java should search for classes.

Your Procfile should have something like:
`worker: java -cp target/classes Main`

This will look for the `Main` class in `target/classes` where Maven saves compiled class files. If you use a different build tool, the directory is different. The above command also does not include your dependencies in the classpath.

Still assuming you're using Maven, you can use [Maven's dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy your dependencies to a directory and include that directory in the `-cp` argument within the Procfile.

Comment: Thx for the advice. How would I include dependencies in my classpath? How would it look like?